# Print contents of scrollable div

Tags: html, css, printing

I have a contract that is being displayed in a scrollable div. I'd like to give my users the ability to print the contents of the scrollable div. The div is roughly three pages long. I'm using bootstrap for this application and have tried the 'visible-print' css class available to me. When I test the print functionality now, only what's in the top of the scrollable div is displayed in the chrome print preview screen with a vertical scrollbar and it cuts off the remaining content.

CSS:

```
#scrollableDiv{
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

@media print,
 (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 5/4),
 (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
 (min-resolution: 120dpi) {
}

@media print {
* {
    background: transparent !important;
    color: #000 !important; /* Black prints faster: h5bp.com/s */
    box-shadow: none !important;
    text-shadow: none !important;
  }

  thead {
    display: table-header-group; /* h5bp.com/t */
  }

  tr,
  img {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }

  img {
    max-width: 100% !important;
  }

  @page {
    margin: 0.5cm;
  }

  p,
  h2,
  h3 {
    orphans: 3;
    widows: 3;
  }

  h2,
  h3 {
    page-break-after: avoid;
  }

  .visible-print {
    display: block !important;
    overflow: visible;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="scrollableDiv" class="margin-bottom-20">
    <div class="visible-print">
        <!-- CONTRACT CONTENTS HERE -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is `#scrollabeDiv` the only thing that needs to be printed? Have you considered opening the same content in a blank window and `window.print()` it, to avoid printing the rest of the page? Would that work for you?

Comment: That is a possibility. Is there a way to do that without sacrificing the UX? I'm not sure how users would feel about having the contract rendered on a separate page/tab then having to hit the print button.

Comment: I feel like it's ok to open the printable content in a new window. You can trigger the print command by running `window.print()` on the target, so users won't have to actually hit the print button. Please also try the answer given by @Sun_Sparxz and tell us if it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
  @media print {
                 #scrollableDiv{
                  width: 100%;
                  height: 100%;
                 }
               .visible-print{
                 display: block;
                 width: auto;
                 height: auto;
                 overflow: visible;  
                }
               }
```

Comment: Still only rendering the first page of the div in the print preview in chrome with the scrollbar on the side.

Comment: I gave it a try and had a very similar outcome. A few more lines of text were displayed on the page. I'm still very confused. I'll continue working on this problem this evening and report back.

Comment: I had about 20 style sheets and I went through each one to see which one was causing the error.. I found a legacy sheet that should've been removed that was causing the error. I then added back your @media print code and it worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

While this is not the exact answer to your solution, you could look at this sample:

http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.CustomTipsTricks.ContinuedTableHeaders

The table in that sample inside a scrollable area and the whole table renders to PDF. We developed this solution for rendering to overcome many of the limitations in a simple browser-based print.

Answer (score 1):

Sun_Sparxz's answer above is solid enough, but I would add a tricky issue you may run into...

After a few hours I realized I had a 'position:fixed' in my body tag which was preventing the above solution from working.  Make sure you remove that or your print logic may not work.  Once I did, the media tag operated as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has just nagged me for a few hours: Ensure that in your CSS instructions #scrollableDiv and .visible-print are defined BEFORE you re-define them under the *@media print* section, otherwise it will not work.