# ElectronJS print HTML document height problems

Tags: reactjs, html, printing, electron, thermal-printer

I'm working on a **ElectronJS** and **Reactjs** project to build an application that prints documents (as web HTML format) using thermal printers.

**Thermal printers** prints documents on special papers with 50mm or 80 mm of width but it has no limits of height.

I use Reactjs to generate HTML Contents and CSS3 print media style to hide screen contents `#root` and show only what i want to print `#print`,

```
@media only print {
  @page {
    size: auto;   /* auto is the initial value */
    margin: 0;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
    height: auto !important;
    width: 70mm !important;
  }

  html, body {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: #eee !important;
    font-family: 'Tahoma', 'Segoe UI Light', 'Segoe UI', 'Helvetica Neue Light', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif !important;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: auto !important;
    width: 70mm !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
  }

  #root {
    display: none !important;
    visibility: hidden !important;
  }

  #print {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    visibility: initial !important;
    padding: 1px !important;
    background: white;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    margin-left: 5mm;
    height: auto !important;
    width: 70mm !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
  }
}
```

The problem is when i try to print long pages, it print only the upper part of it. I figure out that it is **related somehow with the screen height**. Because it print the exact same part that appear when i show the print scope and it **ignore the scrollable part of the document**.

```
webContents.print({ silent: true, printBackground: false, printerName },() => {});
```

I think my issue is very close to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16848669/how-to-print-scrollable-div-content).

Any idea will be helpful,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it.
I just remove `position: fixed;` from both `html, body` and `#print`.