# How to print an entire conversation from Google Messages

Tags: android, printing, sms, android-messaging

I need to print out an entire text conversation that I had on Messages on my phone to submit it to someone's supervisor. When I try to print it on the website it only gives a screenshot of what I am looking it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate on a computer to [the web interface](https://messages.google.com/web)
2. Open the conversation that you want to print
3. Scroll up until the entire conversation is loaded
4. [Open the Javascript console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/77337)
5. Copy and paste the Javascript below into the console and hit enter

```js
(function() {
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
    var printReport= document.querySelector("mws-messages-list");
    document.body.innerHTML = printReport.innerHTML;
    document.body.style.display = 'block';
    document.body.style.overflow = 'visible';
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}())
```

Thank you [AbhiNickz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3014263/abhinickz) for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30077759/2249725) as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Google messages updated their divs:

```
(function() {
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
    var printReport= document.querySelector("body > mw-app > mw-bootstrap > div > main > mw-main-container > div > mw-conversation-container > div > div > div > mws-messages-list")
    document.body.innerHTML = printReport.innerHTML;
    document.body.style.display = 'block';
    document.body.style.overflow = 'visible';
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}())
```